# "grub package failed to install into /target/". Error installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, windows-10

(actually installing Xubuntu but I don't think it makes a difference)

When I attempt to install Ubuntu after setting up the partitions and beginning installation, I end up with a "the 'grub-efi-amd-64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader, the installed system will not boot" error and the install cannot continue.

What led to the current situation:
So I previously had Kubuntu installed dualbooting alongside Win10, long story short I formatted the Kubuntu partition, so I've only got Windows installed atm.
Grub then proceeded to break, but with a Win10 iso I managed to 'repair' it (via bootrec /fixmbr, stuff like that). 
On boot I now get a grub console, if I 'exit' Windows will then boot.

Windows is installed in legacy mode if it matters, not UEFI.

Comment: It's been a way long time since I blew up grub but this link may help you at least boot Ubuntu.  From there it should be a simple matter to fix grub.  https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

Comment: @jones0610 I've got no Ubuntu installed atm but this will probably come in handy later, thanks!

Comment: Windows is installed in legacy-mode. Xubuntu needs to be installed in the same mode. Reinstall Xubuntu, but make sure to boot in legacy-mode, how you boot is how you install. If you want to install in UEFI-mode, it is possible, but you would need ESP (EFI System Partition). The problem then is that Grub can handle dual-boot only for OS's installed in the same boot-mode, so better to install in legacy-mode!